# Surprising behaviour of class variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I have two classes :

```
class BaseSpreadsheetReportView(APIView):
    mapping = {}

    def post(self, request):
        self.mapping['test'] = 'Test'

class EventLogReport(BaseSpreadsheetReportView):

    # business logic
```

I am calling `EventLogReport` but I observed that the same mapping object was shared with all instances of `EventLogReport`.

So for the first request mapping object was empty but for the second request it contained 'test'.

Doubts:

1. Does python share the same object with all threads and instances?
2. if class variables are common for all threads and instances then overriding the values will be an issue in Race condition?

Comment: Well, yeah. It's a class variable. Did you want an instance variable?

Comment: Only variables that are inside `self` like `self.mapping` would be specific to an instance instead of the whole class.

Comment: But garbage collector must delete the mapping value after execution.

Comment: It's possible that something else is going on here, since `mapping['test'] = 'Test'` shouldn't be able to access a class variable from inside of a method. Can you give a [MCVE]?

Comment: @rdas: That's not entirely correct, because you can *access* class variables via any instance. It's only *rebinding* of variables via `self` that will create a new instance attribute if one doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Blckknght it's self.mapping['test'] = 'Test'. sorry i did a mistake during copy paste.

Answer (score 2):

The `mapping` variable is a class variable. Class variables in python are initialized only once(like static variables). If you want your `mapping` variable to be reinitialized on each instance of the `EventLogReport` class, then make the `mapping` variable as an instance variable.

```
class BaseSpreadsheetReportView(APIView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mapping = {}

    def post(self, request):
        self.mapping['test'] = 'Test'

class EventLogReport(BaseSpreadsheetReportView):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseSpreadsheetReportView.__init__(self)

    # business logic
```

Also, there is a typo. If you want to access a class variable, either you use the class name to access the class variable or the method must be a class method or an instance method.

Using class name:

```
class BaseSpreadsheetReportView(APIView):
    mapping = {}

    def post(self, request):
        BaseSpreadsheetReportView.mapping['test'] = 'Test'
```

Using class method:

```
class BaseSpreadsheetReportView(APIView):
    mapping = {}

    @classmethod
    def post(cls, request):
        cls.mapping['test'] = 'Test'
```

Using instance method

```
class BaseSpreadsheetReportView(APIView):
    mapping = {}

    def post(self, request):
        self.mapping['test'] = 'Test'
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `self.mapping['test'] = 'Test'` would work in your second code block. However, rebinding `self.mapping` (rather than mutating it in place) would create a new instance variable that would shadow the class variable.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for notifying it!. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @bumblebee i have tested using third approach(Using instance method) but i did in different way.
class BaseSpreadsheetReportView(APIView):
    mapping = {}
    def post(self, request):
        temp = self.mapping
        self.mapping['test'] = 'Test'
for first Req:- temp is {} and for second request temp is :- {'test': 'Test'}

Comment: and if mapping is static then it must exist only in single instance per class.

Comment: @ArvindKumar I am not able to understand your query. Can yoy please explain it more clearly?

Comment: so if i am using self.mapping['test'] = 'Test' then it must create a new object of mapping for each instance right ?My query is why it's sharing the same instance with both requests.

Comment: @ArvindKumar No, it will not. Using `self.mapping` is just a way of accessing the variable. Python implicitly will use the `BaseSpreadsheetReportView` clas` to call the variable when `self` is used (like `BaseSpreadsheetReportView.mapping`).